# Git command line equivalent of GitHub app's magic stashing?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, git-stash

According to the GitHup app documentation, "*when you switch branches, GitHub [for Mac] performs **magic stashing***" (e.g., see the end of [this](https://help.github.com/articles/why-did-my-changes-disappear-when-switching-branches/) page).

Does anyone know the git command line equivalent of this "magic stashing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are working on the branch *current-branch*. Basically, what happens in Git-terms:

```
git stash
git checkout other-branch
```

Then, when you checkout *current-branch* again. The following happens

```
git stash pop
```

The [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) stores the uncommitted changes in the working directory. When you return the branch, a git stash pop is used to grab the uncommitted changes from the stash and place them on top of the *current-branch*

Comment: If the GitHub app branch switch just uses the 'git stash' command then why do they call it 'magic stashing'?  The 'magic' qualifier gives the impression that more is going on.

Comment: It is magic in the sense it different from the normal functionality in Git. In Git switching between branches will cause any uncommitted changes to be moved to the other-branch. Switching in the Github-client will cause the changes to be stored and not moved to the other branch. So like usual the magic is not very complicated.

Bare in mind that my explanation regarding the stashing is just a simplified/general version. The client could be using more advanced functionality, or use a different implementation. However, the concept remains the same.